# How does some apps record calls in android 10?

Tags: java, audio-recording, android-studio-3.0, android-10.0, call-recording

We all know that android disabled call recording feature starting from version 6.

And some workarounds were found for android 7 and 8 (https://gitter.im/CallRec-net/Lobby?source=orgpage) which worked fine for some device models.

But staring from android 9 such workarounds also stopped working. (At least I couldn't find a working solution, if somebody has found a working solution please post below)

But recently i saw that some third party call recording apps claims that they are successfully doing it for android 10. The common factor of all these apps are that, they are using android accessibility service API.

Here is one such link, they claim that they had make call recording working for samsung S10 with android 10 (non root). 
https://www.boldbeast.com/forum/topic1877-android-10-call-recording.html

I tried to figure out how an accessibility service can be used for call recording but ended in failure. So what might be the procedure that above mentioned third party apps are using for call recording?

Please guide me on the steps of making a call recording possible with the help of an accessibility service for android 10 (non root). It would be a great help if someone could explain with some working code snipped so that many will get benefited.

Comment: do you find solution yet...?

Comment: by using `Accessibilty` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230181/call-recorder-not-working-in-android-10-q/64012110#64012110)