# Android recorded incoming and outgoing calls are silent

Tags: java, android

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    TextView textSubHeader;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        textSubHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSubHeader);
//        File CallRecorder = new File("/sdcard/CallRecorder");
//        CallRecorder.mkdirs();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Runtime permission
        try {
            boolean permissionGranted_OutgoingCalls = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean permissionGranted_phoneState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean permissionGranted_recordAudio = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean permissionGranted_WriteExternal = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            boolean permissionGranted_ReadExternal = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            
            if (permissionGranted_OutgoingCalls) {
                if (permissionGranted_phoneState) {
                    if (permissionGranted_recordAudio) {
                        if (permissionGranted_WriteExternal) {
                            if (permissionGranted_ReadExternal) {
                                try {
                                    toggleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 200);
                            }
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 300);
                        }
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 400);
                    }
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 500);
                }
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS}, 600);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    public void toggleButtonClick(View view) {
        try {
            boolean checked = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
            if (checked) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallRecorder.class);
                startService(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Recording is set ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textSubHeader.setText("Switch on Toggle to record your calls");
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallRecorder.class);
                stopService(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Recording is set OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textSubHeader.setText("Switch Off Toggle to stop recording your calls");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 200 || requestCode == 300 || requestCode == 400 || requestCode == 500 || requestCode == 600) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    toggleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CallRecorder extends Service {
        private MediaRecorder recorder;
        private boolean recordStarted = false;
        private String savedNumber;
        public static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
        public static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
        public static final String EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER = "android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER";
        private int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        private boolean isIncoming;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
            filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
            this.registerReceiver(new CallReceiver(), filter);
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        private void stopRecording() {
            if (recordStarted) {
                recorder.stop();
                recordStarted = false;
            }
        }

    public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                savedNumber = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            }  else {
            String stateStr = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
             savedNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }
                onCallStateChanged(context, state, savedNumber);

        }
    }

        protected abstract void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number);

        protected abstract void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number);

        protected abstract void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number);

        protected abstract void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number);

        protected abstract void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number);

        protected abstract void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number);

        public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
            String time =  dateFormat.format(new Date()) ;

            File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/indcallrecorder");
            if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                sampleDir.mkdirs();
            }

            if (lastState == state) {
                return;
            }
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    isIncoming = true;
                    savedNumber = number;
                    onIncomingCallReceived(context, number );

                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//                    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(sampleDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Incoming \n" + number + "  \n" + time + "  \n" + " Call.amr");

                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    recorder.start();
                    recordStarted = true;

                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        isIncoming = false;

                        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                        recorder.setOutputFile(sampleDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Outgoing \n" + savedNumber + "  \n" + time + "  \n" + " Call.amr");

                        try {
                            recorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        recorder.start();
                        recordStarted = true;

                        onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber );

                    } else {
                        isIncoming = true;
                        onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber);
                    }

                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        onMissedCall(context, savedNumber);
                    } else if (isIncoming) {

                        stopRecording();

                        onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber);
                    } else {

                        stopRecording();

                        onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            lastState = state;
        }
    }

    public class CallReceiver extends PhoneCallReceiver {
        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number) {
        }
    }

  }
```

I am implementing call recording option in my Android application and all the calls are recoding fine below Android version 10 but from Android version 10 to above versions calls are recorded and when I try to play the recorded calls its silent. I am not able to listen the recorded voice.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Check this link, might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230181/call-recorder-not-working-in-android-10-q

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call recorder not working in android 10 (Q)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230181/call-recorder-not-working-in-android-10-q)

Comment: @YakirMalka the link which you provided is asking to install third party application to record calls.I don't want to install any applications to record calls.i want to implement the feature inside my application

Comment: @Vishali it was stating you can do it with Accessibility Service.

Comment: @YakirMalka i have done with accessibility service but calls are not recoding destination voice on above 10 version

Comment: below 10  versions no issues everything working cool

Comment: @YakirMalka so can you please suggest me something to work from android version 10