# Android application for Call Record even though app not in background

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-studio

Android application to make a call recorder to maintain the history of the call with it's recording of what they speak. it's for sales team not for every we are not going to publish this app to play store.
if it's not possible we can create the application for routed mobile we can route the mobile also

Creating a app to record the calls

Comment: You can get the callbacks for system events and when you receive it in your app then you can start a foreground service and using work manager, you can start whatever task you want to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There may be permission issues with recording incoming call audio. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231232/android-call-recording-incoming-voice-not-getting-recorded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231232/android-call-recording-incoming-voice-not-getting-recorded) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230181/call-recorder-not-working-in-android-10-q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230181/call-recorder-not-working-in-android-10-q)